# Training data for image digit recognition

Tags: data, image-classification

I am creating a digit image recognition algorithm. For this I would like to collect sample data to train the model. Does python have any inbuilt libraries for this? Where could I get good training data and testing data for this?

Comment: Do you mean something like [MNIST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database)? // I don’t think this Stack does data requests, so this might get closed for being off-topic, but we do have such a Stack, something like Open Data.

Comment: mnist is available through keras.datasets  --> https://keras.io/api/datasets/

Comment: Thanks. Which algorithm will be best for digit classification? Is there a better one compared to the simplest, KNN ?

Comment: NN or CCN could be a good start. You can read here about MNIST and NN : https://medium.com/tebs-lab/how-to-classify-mnist-digits-with-different-neural-network-architectures-39c75a0f03e3